# Way of Avoid Docker on Django Channels

Tags: django, docker, django-channels

I'm developing an app with django and althougth I don't understant Docker, I ended with this code for establish the connections on django channels:

```
sudo docker run -p 6379:6379 -d redis:5
```

And `settings.py`:

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [('127.0.0.1', 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

I'm facing losts of issues trying to obtain the same result without need to use that. (technical requirements, I can't use Docker)
I'm sorry if the question is dumb, but is there any way of running that port connection without docker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to be able to use django-channels you need to have redis running on your system. Redis can be used for [many things (it is used as message-broker in django-channels)](https://redis.io/topics/introduction) and you can install it either through docker as you did or regularly on your operating system.

For example to install redis on your ubuntu operating system you can run

```
sudo apt-get install redis-server
```

you can then always start the redis server before running your Django Channels project with the command

```
redis-server
```

To avoid that you can configure redis to start everytime after you boot up your operating system like this:

```
sudo systemctl enable redis-server.service
```

Comment: And I will need to configure the port on redis or it's not necessary? Because, then, in settings.py I call that port (i edited my question with that part of my code)

Comment: No, 6379 is the default port for redis. So when you don't specify any port that is the port that redis will use by default. You only need to specify a port if you would like to use a diferent port than the default.